# How to set Convert Zero Datetime in Entity Framework connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-5

I am trying to connect to MySQL database using Entity Framework 5. Everything works fine when using the connection string supplied by app.config:

```
<add name="MHEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=server.example.com;user id=username;password=pass;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=dbname;convertzerodatetime=True;characterset=utf8&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

However, I need to create the connection in code (I want to be able to supply the db password at runtime). So far I have the following code:

```
      SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(@"Convert Zero Datetime=true;");
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = "server.example.com";
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = "dbname";
        sqlBuilder.UserID = "username";
        sqlBuilder.Password = "password";
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
      //  sqlBuilder.Add("convertzerodatetime", "true");

        string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl";
        entityBuilder.Provider = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

        ConnString = entityBuilder.ConnectionString;

        MHEntities context = new MHEntities(ConnString);
```

And that works. But as soon as I uncomment the one line in the code above, I get an exception:

> Keyword not supported: 'convertzerodatetime'. I tried "Convert Zero Datetime" with same results.

I need this setting (Convert Zero Datetime=true), because without it the app fails when it tries to load datetime values from the database with all zeros (I have no control over those).

Comment: `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` is for MS's own `SqlConnection` connections, not for MySQL or other providers. You'll need to look for an alternative for MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as error message says, SqlConnectionStringBuilder does not support the convertzerodatetime keyword. Consider using the [MySqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://mysql-connector-net.sourcearchive.com/documentation/6.1.2/classMySql_1_1Data_1_1MySqlClient_1_1MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

'Convert Zero Datetime' works on EF 6, can you update your library? Try to change your web.config from 'convertzerodatetime=True' to 'Convert Zero Datetime=True'.

```
<add name="MHEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=server.example.com;user id=username;password=pass;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=dbname;characterset=utf8;Convert Zero Datetime=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```